# When to removeObserver for non-ViewController objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an object which is doing its removeObserver in dealloc() and am getting lots of crash reports for objc_msgsend when the handler is called.

I've read that best practice is to removeObserver in viewWillDisappear, as dealloc() does not insure state - but this object is not a viewController.

In the case of an object which is *not* a viewController, how should it deregister without the viewWillDisappear method available?

I can removeObserver from the viewController.viewWillDissappear which owns the object instance, but that is important, invisible magic to other callers who may use the same class.

Comment: You could use `- willMoveToSuperview` and look for `nil`.

Comment: Thanks Jorf - I should have clarified - the object is not a view either :(

Comment: Just a thought - the dealloc is called when there are no longer strong refs to the object, are you sure that the dealloc is called?

Comment: Oren I will check this by debugging on handset - but if dealloc isn't being called, then wouldn't my object still exist when handling the notification? Or are you saying that in an ARC environment, the object can be released without an explicit call to dealloc()?

Comment: Just an update - I would up just moving the de/registration to the owning viewController's viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear - should move the handler itself as well...